# Where does the O/P goes when it is redirected to /dev/null

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

Whenever anything is redirected to `/dev/null`,

```
user$ echo "Redirecting output to null" > /dev/null
```

where does the output actually flushes or if it is written to /dev/null (as from the man pages which says it is similar like simply writing to a file), then when it is cleared out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `null` device simply reads everything written to it, and discards it.

It's like you reading a file, but not storing it anywhere, just throwing it away.

Comment: Where does the output is discarded off, means by discarding, do we mean simply deallocating the memory allocated to it or any process takes care of it or OS takes care of it?

Comment: @pRAShANT If you have a program that reads data from a file, but doesn't store that data anywhere, where does that end up? Nowhere. It's just the same, it may be as simple as read a byte into a variable, then read the next by into the same variable, then read the next byte into the same variable, etc.

Comment: Ok, but in case of variable it would overwrite the value in the memory allocated to the variable but my doubt was regarding weather it just start deallocating the memory as it start redirecting or puts in a space where it or some system daemon takes care of it

Comment: @pRAShANT There are of course lots of buffers between your redirection and the actual `null` device reading and discarding the data, but that's all handled by either the shell or the operating system. How the shell and operating system handles those buffers is the same as for any other file, just that once it reaches the `null` device driver the data is discarded instead of e.g. written to a file.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/null` isn't a regular file.

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null):

> In Unix-like operating systems, `/dev/null` or the null device is a
>   special file that discards all data written to it but reports that the
>   write operation succeeded. It provides no data to any process that
>   reads from it, yielding `EOF` immediately.[[1]](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap10.html)